# Format pandas datatime object to show fiscal years from Feb to Feb and be formatted as %Y?

Tags: python, date, datetime, formatting, pandas

I have a series of timestamps like so,

```
3   2013-08-23 00:00:00
4   2008-09-21 00:00:00
5   2012-03-17 00:00:00
6   2011-12-31 00:00:00
7   2011-11-16 00:00:00
8   2008-01-23 00:00:00
9   2010-06-13 00:00:00
```

I want to convert them to Fiscal Years in the format 2010, 2011 etc. The fiscal Year runs FEB-JAN.
I am confused- do I need to use offset? How do I change the represention from a timestamp to just the fiscal year portion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. Unlikely to be the best one or if so that's serendipity for you.

```
 df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df.DATE).apply(pd.Period, freq='A-FEB')
```

Comment: I think there must be a better way- this takes 100 secs on a series of 500000

Answer (score 5):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE).dt.to_period('A-JAN')
```

Should be faster and what you want, as `A-JAN` is a fiscal year that *ends* in January, as opposed to `A-FEB`, which ends in February. See the [description of the frequency strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) for more information.